# How to print an int and a string with spaces after using printf?

Tags: c, printf, spaces

I usually use `printf("%-8d",a);` for example for 8 spaces after (and including) an integer.
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
    
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    char b = "Hello";
}
```

How can I print: `'#10-Hello        '`
with 16 spaces (8 is the integer and the string, and 8 spaces after)?

Comment: `char b = "Hello"` is a syntactic error, use array of char instead

Comment: Please show exactly what you want to get as output.

Comment: @Gerhardh I fixed his formatting so it's clear what he wants

Comment: So, "spaces" does not mean spaces (`' '`) but any characters in the output.

Comment: He wants to print `#a-b` in a 16-character field with space padding.

Comment: Do you want this `printtf("#%d-Hello        ", a)`? It's very unclear what output you actually want. [Edit] and show the __verbatim__ output you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in two steps. First combine the number and string with `sprintf()`, then print that resulting string in a 16-character field.

```
int a = 10;
char *b = "Hello";
char temp[20];
sprintf(temp, "#%d-%s", a, b);
printf("%-16s", temp);
```

Comment: Perhaps `snprintf()` to ward off buffer overruns with updated code?

Answer (score 0):

A tab is 8 spaces, so, you can add \t\t
The below is a super basic way to print what you wanted.

```
printf('#' + a + '-' + b + '\t\t');
```

I'm not as familiar with the syntax of C so it may be :

```
printf('#', a, '-', b, '\t\t');
```

Also, as mentioned in a previous answer, "Hello" is not a char but either an array of char or a String.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
    
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    char b[] = "Hello";
    printf("#%d-%-17s",a,b);
}
```

this should get the job done, adjust your spacing as needed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Could do this with 2 `printf()`s.  Use the return value of the first to know its print length, then print spaces needed to form a width of 16.  No temporary buffer needed.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int width = 16;
    int a = 10;
    char *b = "Hello"; // Use char *

    int len = printf("#%d-%s", a, b);
    assert(len <= width && len >= 0);
    printf("%*s", width - len, "");  // Print spaces
}
```